# message queue mutilple receiver implementation

Tags: c, message-queue

The broadcasting program is this.I have used 3 different keys and yet only the first listener gets the message.the other's get a message sending error.The keys should identify different user shouldn't it??

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/msg.h>
#include <pthread.h>

struct msgbuf
{
long mtype;
char mtext[140];
}send_buf,recv_buf;

int send_msg_id,send_msg_id1,send_msg_id2;
key_t send_key,send_key1,send_key2;

int main()
{
send_key=ftok("broadcast.c",'A');
send_key1=ftok("broadcast.c",'B');
send_key2=ftok("broadcast.c",'C');
char save[140];
if (send_key==-1)
{
    perror("\nCaller send key error(ftok)");
    exit(1);
}
send_msg_id=msgget(send_key,0666 | IPC_CREAT);
send_msg_id1=msgget(send_key,0555 | IPC_CREAT);
send_msg_id2=msgget(send_key,0777 | IPC_CREAT);
if (send_msg_id==-1)
{   
    printf("\nCaller send msgget error");
    exit(1);
}
printf("\nCALLER:");
while (fgets(send_buf.mtext,sizeof(send_buf.mtext),stdin)!=NULL)
{
    send_buf.mtype=1;
    int len=strlen(send_buf.mtext);
    strcpy(save,send_buf.mtext);
    if (send_buf.mtext[len-1]=='\n');
        send_buf.mtext[len-1]='\0';
    if (msgsnd(send_msg_id,&send_buf,len+1,0)==-1)
        printf("\nMsg sending error\n");
    strcpy(send_buf.mtext,save);
    if (msgsnd(send_msg_id1,&send_buf,len+1,0)==-1)
        perror("\nMsg sending error (send_msg_id1)");
    strcpy(send_buf.mtext,save);
    if (msgsnd(send_msg_id2,&send_buf,len+1,0)==-1)
        perror("\nMsg sending error (send_msg_id2)");
}
int i=0;
while(i<9999)
    i++;
msgctl(send_msg_id,IPC_RMID,NULL);
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed a few possible issues while reviewing your code.

First, you call `msgget()` three times.  Each time you use the same key stored in the variable `send_key`.  I believe this code should be:

```
send_msg_id= msgget(send_key,  0666 | IPC_CREAT);
send_msg_id1=msgget(send_key1, 0555 | IPC_CREAT);
send_msg_id2=msgget(send_key2, 0777 | IPC_CREAT);
```

Note the changing of `send_key` to `send_key1` in the second line and `send_key` to `send_key3` in the third line.

Second, the values `0666`, `0555`, and `0777` represent the permissions for the message queue.  As described by the msgget() manual page:

> Upon  creation,  the least significant bits of the argument msgflg define the permissions of the message queue.  These permission bits have the same format and semantics as the permissions specified for the mode argument of open(2).  (The execute permissions are not used.)

Thus, `0666` gives read/write permissions to all, `0555` gives read permissions to all, and `0777` gives read/write permission to all  (the execute bit is ignored as noted in the manual page).  This probably wasn't your intent.  The simplest change would be to make these all `0666` for read/write (or 0600 if you want to restrict access to only your user).  `0555` will be a problem as it is read-only.  So, the above is further changed to:

```
send_msg_id= msgget(send_key,  0666 | IPC_CREAT);
send_msg_id1=msgget(send_key1, 0666 | IPC_CREAT);
send_msg_id2=msgget(send_key2, 0666 | IPC_CREAT);
```

Third, you only check the return codes for the first `ftok` and `msgget` calls.  You should probably check the return code from all three to ensure there isn't a problem there.